# In Cypress how to extract the error message?

Tags: cypress

Automating cypress. Attaching the screenshot. How can I extract the error message "Password must be greater than 8 characters"? Input is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Some additional info, when I inspect the HTML following is what I see.

[image]

How can I grab the text "Password must be greater than 8 characters"

Comment: Add the HTML of the page when the error is appearing.

Answer (score 3):

It is not in the the HTML of the page, it is a property of the element that is displayed directly by the browser.

To access it, you will use [HTMLObjectElement.validationMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/validationMessage).

Your test will be something like this code:

```js
cy.get('#password').its('validationMessage').should('contain', 'Password must be greater than 8 characters')
```